# Character rotates but only moves towards one direction. (Unity 2d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am unable to "move" the character towards the "left" direction. It moves only towards "right" direction when I press both, "a" AND "d".
However, I am able to rotate the character to either direction according to the key pressed.

It is kind of moonwalking when I press the left key, I don't want my character to follow the footsteps of the late MJ.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{

    //On X axis: -1f is left, 1f is right
    //Player Movement. Check for horizontal movement
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            moveSpeed = runSpeed;
        }
        else {
            moveSpeed = 5f;
        }
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));
        if (rb2d.velocity.y == 0 && !isslashing)
            animator.Play("player_run");
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f && !facingRight)
        {
            //If we're moving right but not facing right, flip the sprite and set     facingRight to true.
            Flip();
            facingRight = true;

        }
        else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0.5f && facingRight)
        {
            //If we're moving left but not facing left, flip the sprite and set facingRight to false.
            Flip();
            facingRight = false;
        }


    }

    else
    {
        if (rb2d.velocity.y == 0 && !isslashing)
            animator.Play("idleanim");
    }
}


void Flip()

{

    //Switch the way the player is labelled as facing

    facingRight = !facingRight;

    transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) defaults to moving in local space and since you're rotating the transform, it's easiest if you just have it move in world space since you are already creating a world space vector.

You can do this by adding `Space.World` as an argument to `Transform.Translate`:

```
         Vector3 moveVector = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed 
                              * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.right;
         transform.Translate(moveVector, Space.World);
```

By the way, you're already toggling the value of `movingRight` inside of `Flip`, so there is no reason to set it again after you call `Flip`.  Might as well just call it and be done with those blocks:

```
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f && !facingRight)
        {
            // If we're moving right but not facing right, flip the sprite
            // and set facingRight to true.
            Flip();
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0.5f && facingRight)
        {
            // If we're moving left but not facing left, flip the sprite 
            // and set facingRight to false.
            Flip();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked. So correct me if I'm wrong, the transform.translate i assigned in the beginning was local hence it was overridden by the transform in Flip() which was a world vector?

Comment: @Solloski First, the [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) you do in Flip is in local space because you didn't give it a `Space.World` argument. Second, the rotation you do in `Flip`cancels out the positive and negative of `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` when translating locally. That would be the case whether the rotation was done in local or world space.